# Python recursion assignment error

Tags: python, recursion

This is my code:

```
def prifact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []

    def prifactHelper(x):
        if x == 1:
            return []
        else:
            for i in range(2,x+1):
                if x % i == 0:
                    return [i] + prifactHelper(x/i)

    return prifactHelper(n)
```

This is my error:

```
local variable 'prifactHelper' referenced before assignment
```

I have properly defined the function "prifactHelper" so, I can't figure out what's going on.

**Update:**

The code works fine, apparently I had an indentation error, which I corrected while parsing my code to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please use more than one space for indentation, four spaces is pretty standard. Also, the code your pasted throws an indentation error (return outside of function). Please check that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def prifact(n):
    if n == 0:
    return []

    def prifactHelper(x):
        if x == 1:
            return []
        else:
            for i in range(2, int(x+1)):
                if x % i == 0:
                    return [i] + prifactHelper(x/i)

    return prifactHelper(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(prifact(10))
```

Output `[2, 5]`. However you need to make call `range` with integer, in other way you have a possibility to get `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. So call `range(2, int(x+1))`, instead of just `range(2, x+1)`

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the integer conversation.